# Validate property against another with JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

In the model below, "category_id" property should be required only if "detail" array is empty.

If "detail" array is not empty, "category_id" property is not required.

How can I do this with JSON Schema?

```
{
    "description": "Expense model validation.",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "description": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "category_id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "detail": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "description": "Expense detail",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "description": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [ "description" ]
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [ "description", "category_id" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `anyOf` to check that either `category_id` is present, or `detail` is present and has at least one item.

```
{
  "description": "Expense model validation.",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "description": { "type": "string" },
    "category_id": { "type": "string" },
    "detail": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "description": "Expense detail",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "description": { "type": "string" }
        },
        "required": ["description"]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["description"],
  "anyOf": [
    { "required": ["category_id"] },
    {
      "properties": {
        "detail": { "minItems": 1 }
      },
      "required": ["detail"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Using anyOf, validation was successful only in this case:

{
    "description": "Expense",
    "detail": [{
        "description": "Expense detail"
        }]
}

But this request should be valid, but was not:
{
    "description": "Expense",
    "category_id": "555cf4fa5a98e36338886ca6"
}

However I changed to use oneOf instead anyOf and it worked perfectly! Tks very much!

Comment: @Diogo, I'm not getting the same results as you are.  Both of the examples  you give validate correctly for me.  `oneOf` should work as well except for the case where `category_id` and `detail` are both present.  `oneOf` requires that only one (not both) of the schemas validate.  If the schema I posted doesn't work, there might be a problem with the validator you are using.

Comment: you're right, anyOf works fine. That was an error in my test payload. Tks again!